# How to send file from iPhone to mac over bluetooth

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

I have created universal device application to transfer any kind of files via bluetooth using GameKit Framework.
My question is how to create on Desktop Application with same process or there any Framework? That can communicate also on the device. Can i have any sample please or tips how to do it.

There is Core Bluetooth that used low energy protocol. But i don't know how?
Anyone please give some idea or anything that i can use it.

Thank you

Comment: You can use GameKit on OS X, but you need to target 10.8 and above.

Comment: borrrden, i use Gamekit framwork to transfer files between iOS device but my issue how i can transfer files from iOS to Mac via bluetooth ??

Comment: I assume it would work the same way in OS X as it does on iOS since the framework is present in both operating systems.

Answer (score 2):

The Bluetooth functionality of the GameKit framework is iOS-only (see [GKSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/)), so you won’t be able to use that on a Mac.

The CoreBluetooth framework on the other hand is available on both Mac and iOS devices supporting Bluetooth LE, with the one difference that the [CBPeripheralManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013015) is not available on Mac, so you can’t advertise a service on Mac. However you can have your iOS device act as a peripheral and connect from the Mac acting as a central. Data transfer should still work both ways.

The [BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code should be a good starting point.